# Javascript contenteditable error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is my html code for displaying a editable textbox and is used as a "memo" element inside a webpage (inside a div tag).

```
contenteditable="true" name="choice1" class="textfield" max="872">Enter your Memo Here!
```

CSS:

```
    .textfield {
  max-width: 800px;
  width: 800px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 8px;
  margin: 20px;
  float:right;
  position: relative;
}
```

Javascript:

```
  var textfields = document.getElementsByClassName("textfield");
  for(i=0; i<textfields.length; i++){
      textfields[i].addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {
          if(this.innerHTML.length >= this.getAttribute("max")){
              e.preventDefault();
              return false;
          }
      }, false);
  }
```

However when I fill the editable div area with alot of spaces (" "), it takes less than the declared 872 characters to reach the maximum limit. Does anyone know why and have a solution? Thanks.

Comment: can you please create a working jsfiddle?

Comment: FYI - the `name` property is for form elements only. For CSS and JavaScript purposes, use the `id` property.

Comment: Add the same event handler to the `keyup` event as well as the `keypress` event to track all the characters properly.

Comment: I'm guessing that the way consecutive spaces (which aren't displayed when HTML is rendered) are stored in a contenteditable div is <space>&nbsp;<space>&nbsp; etc.  Because the length of the innerHTML jumps by five every second space.  Anyway that was just the fun part.  Your real problem is that you are using div.innerHTML.length instead of div.textContent.length

Answer (score 1):

Use `textContent` instead of `innerHTML`.

The textContent property sets or returns the textual content of the specified node, and all its descendants.

The innerHTML property sets or returns the HTML content (inner HTML) of an element.Which will include tags

In the below example I have set the max as `20`

```js
var textfields = document.getElementsByClassName("textfield");
for (i = 0; i < textfields.length; i++) {
  textfields[i].addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {
    if (this.textContent.length >= this.getAttribute("max")) {
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log('max reached') ;
      return false;
    }
  }, false);
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true" name="choice1" class="textfield" max="20">Enter your Memo Here!</div>
```

Comment: Just to make very clear. `innerHTML` asks the HTML parser to treat the content as HTML (to parse it). Doing that strips (normalizes) the extra white space.